# When Adding JButtons Inside a Jpanel using a Method how do I keep the last button added in view?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Whenever I Call my add corePanel or add electivePanel methods They simply replace the last button that was added instead off adding a new one along side in the 4 columns I have set in the Jpanel.

I am aware that I have named the variables Panel when they are really buttons but that is irrelevant.

I really need some help.

Thanks

EDIT:
NOW when I mouse over the buttons all the information (Jpanels) inside of them disappears?

```
package Assignment2.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import ams.model.Course;

public class CoursePanel extends JPanel 
{
private JButton corePanel = new JButton();
private JButton electivePanel = new JButton();
private JLabel ccLabel = new JLabel("Code: ");
private JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
private JLabel cpLabel = new JLabel("Credit Points: ");
private JLabel prLabel = new JLabel("Prereqs: ");
private Border blackline;


public CoursePanel()
{   
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));
}



public void addcorePanel(Course createcourse)
{
    // core panel properties
    blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,10);

    corePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
    corePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    corePanel.setBorder(blackline);
    corePanel.add(ccLabel);
    corePanel.add(titleLabel);
    corePanel.add(cpLabel);
    corePanel.add(prLabel);
    corePanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    corePanel.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    //Needed to rebuild the prerequisites for display.
    String[] prereqs = null;
    String result = null;
    prereqs = createcourse.getPreReqs();

    if (prereqs != null)
    {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : prereqs) 
    {
        builder.append(s);
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    result = builder.toString();
    }
    ccLabel.setText("Code: " + createcourse.getCode());
    titleLabel.setText("Title: " + createcourse.getTitle());
    cpLabel.setText("Credit points: " + Integer.toString(createcourse.getCreditPoints()));
    prLabel.setText("Prereqs: " + result);

    add(corePanel);

}


public void addelectivePanel(Course createcourseE)
{


    //elective panel properties
    electivePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
    electivePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    electivePanel.add(ccLabel);
    electivePanel.add(titleLabel);
    electivePanel.add(cpLabel);
    electivePanel.add(prLabel);
    electivePanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    electivePanel.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    //Needed to rebuild the prerequisites for display.
    String[] prereqs = null;
    String result = null;
    prereqs = createcourseE.getPreReqs();

    if (prereqs != null)
    {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : prereqs) 
    {
        builder.append(s);
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    result = builder.toString();
    }

    ccLabel.setText("Code: " + createcourseE.getCode());
    titleLabel.setText("Title: " + createcourseE.getTitle());
    cpLabel.setText("Credit points: " + Integer.toString(createcourseE.getCreditPoints()));
    prLabel.setText("Prereqs: " + result);


    add(electivePanel);


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your labels and buttons (`corePanel`, `electivePanel`) are class variables, so when you call for example `addcorePanel`, instead of creating a new `JButton` you're manipulating the same `corePanel` button. You should move your variables inside the method body, like this:

```
public void addcorePanel(Course createcourse)
{
    JButton corePanel = new JButton();
    JLabel ccLabel = new JLabel("Code: ");
    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
    JLabel cpLabel = new JLabel("Credit Points: ");
    JLabel prLabel = new JLabel("Prereqs: ");

// ....

// ....
}
```

`JLabels` and `JButtons` cannot be shared so you must create new instances each time you call your methods.

Comment: WOW amazing guys two simple errors on my part and now it works fine thanks alot much appreciated! I had a feeling it was my naive logic. THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

Because `corePanel` is defined as member variable, there is only instance of this component. Therefore it will only appear on one location/column of the panel no matter how many times `addcorePanel` is called.  The same is true for component `electivePanel` as well as every other component used in both both methods.

The solution is to create these are local variables so that new components are created:

```
public void addcorePanel(Course createcourse) {
   // core panel properties
   blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 10);

   // new local instances
   JButton corePanel = new JButton(); 
   JLabel ccLabel = new JLabel("Code: ");
   JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
   JLabel cpLabel = new JLabel("Credit Points: "); 
   // etc.
   ...
   add(corePanel);
}
```

Comment: So how would I make it appear in more than one location please I have been trapped here for almost 5 hours now :S Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are calling `addcorePanel` more than once. If you follow my code above it will create the `JButton` as many times as needed to match the # of columns in the layout.

Comment: OK I am almost there now except when I mouse over the buttons all the information inside of them disappears???

Comment: @user1511032 your `JLabels` must also be local variables, not only the button

Comment: Correct @Rempelos, that will make the inner components appear, +1 to you